# How to align Image View and TexView Right and Left of each other?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

Below is my layout File. But I'm not able to align the Textview (@id/role) and Imageview(@id/flag) left and right of each other. Text appears to be over the ImageView.

Below is my  layout File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/bas" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:text="Xyz Nepal"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/role"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/flag"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text=" Nepali physicist specializing in cosmology. Having worked in the Central Department of Physics for 34 years"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#027e76"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Binil Aryal is the Professor and newly appointed Head of the Department at Central Department of Physics, Tribhuvan University, Kathmandu, Nepal.He was Born in 1969-09-28 in Saptari District of Eastern Nepal.
He is one of the actively working astrophysicist of Nepal. He has been working in the field of Galaxy orientation and Evolution. He has served as a judge of International Astronomy Olympiad. He is the country representative of BCVSPIN school.

He was awarded by 'Mahendra Bidhya Bhushan ka' by the late king Birendra Shah for securing highest score in the M.Sc. Examination. He received 'Third World Academy Award (TWAS)' for his Ph.D. work."
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:text="xyz@gmail.com"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#0d38f7"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

This  is how it appears

[image]

This is what i want

[image]

Thanks in Advance. I did use The  Linearlayou and Relativelayout to position item but  I did a terrible job and also I would like to stretch the textview irrespective of Screen size but don't overlap the image and alwasy stay left of Image.

Comment: Your image view and the text that's overlapping it need to be in the same ViewGroup so they can be referenced in relation to each other. It doesn't really matter which Layout you use. You could use a RelativeLayout and just align the text to the left of the image or use a horizontal LinearLayout like another poster said. The only other alternative would be to align your entire linear layout to the left of the image which I don't think you want to do.

Comment: @jburn2712, Thanks for help..This is how it appeared after I did exactly what I did after dhruv suggested. https://ibb.co/ccsXH7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code see if its what you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="@string/xyz"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/flag"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/launcher"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/role"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/name"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/flag"
    android:text="@string/role
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#027e76"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@id/role"
    android:padding="10dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/desc"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="xyz@gmail.com"
        android:textColor="#0d38f7" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I want.

Comment: We sure are.Nice one

Answer (score 1):

I want to suggest to place text view with id as name and role should be inside separate LinearLayout and adjust to meet required UI.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="horizontal">
     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/bas" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/flag"
        android:orientation="vertical">



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:text="Xyz Nepal"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/role"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/flag"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text=" Nepali physicist specializing in cosmology. Having worked in the Central Department of Physics for 34 years"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#027e76"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

         <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/desc"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Binil Aryal is the Professor and newly appointed Head of the Department at Central Department of Physics, Tribhuvan University, Kathmandu, Nepal.He was Born in 1969-09-28 in Saptari District of Eastern Nepal.
He is one of the actively working astrophysicist of Nepal. He has been working in the field of Galaxy orientation and Evolution. He has served as a judge of International Astronomy Olympiad. He is the country representative of BCVSPIN school.

He was awarded by 'Mahendra Bidhya Bhushan ka' by the late king Birendra Shah for securing highest score in the M.Sc. Examination. He received 'Third World Academy Award (TWAS)' for his Ph.D. work."
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

          <TextView
             android:padding="5dp"
             android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:text="xyz@gmail.com"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#0d38f7"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/flag"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/capture" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/flag"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:text="Xyz Nepal"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/role"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/flag"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text=" Nepali physicist specializing in cosmology. Having worked in the Central Department of Physics for 34 years"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#027e76"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="Binil Aryal is the Professor and newly appointed Head     of the Department at Central Department of Physics, Tribhuvan University, Kathmandu, Nepal.He was Born in 1969-09-28 in Saptari District of Eastern Nepal.
He is one of the actively working astrophysicist of Nepal. He has been working in the field of Galaxy orientation and Evolution. He has served as a judge of International Astronomy Olympiad. He is the country representative of BCVSPIN school.

He was awarded by 'Mahendra Bidhya Bhushan ka' by the late king Birendra Shah for securing highest score in the M.Sc. Examination. He received 'Third World Academy Award (TWAS)' for his Ph.D. work."
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/ll"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:text="xyz@gmail.com"
        android:layout_below="@id/desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#0d38f7"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a vertical linear layout (by default vertical) and put the image view and text view (first text view example-xyz nepal) in it . And rest in linear horizontal layout for other text view(example-the green color text and others ) it will definitely solve your problem

Comment: THe next two should be in horizontal linear layout not vertical . Put the next two in linear layout and add the orientation to horizontal.